# JavaScript document.cookie has less info than Chrome cookie resource explorer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

When I print out `document.cookie` in the Chrome console, I see the following...

```
document.cookie
"__qca=P0-1877502676-1384254012269; 
__utma=140029553.512150271.1384254012.1388335027.1388410832.76; 
__utmz=140029553.1388335027.75.53.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); 
_ga=GA1.2.512150271.1384254012"
```

But when I look into the Resources > cookies tab I see the following...

[image: Screen shot of Chrome cookies]

It seems `document.cookie` isn't returing all the cookies that Chrome is reporting in the Resources tab.

Anyone know why this is? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you trying to use the cookies on the stackoverflow.com site?  Cookies are domain specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies can be set to http-only mode by the server, it tells the browser to not give javascript access to them.

Comment: Okay, that'd be why then :) Thanks!